# get sum of a column and a value inputted in textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

i have a textbox named AddU.text, i also have a msaccess table field named Quantity, what I want is that when i input a value in AddU.Text and click the add button, the value i entered will be automatically add to the existing value in Quantity. I keep searching for solution but can't find the right one. Can anyone help me? Heres my current codes:

```
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    If Not conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        conn.Open()
    End If
    Try
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE BC_Inventory SET [Addition]='" + AddU.Text + "'," + _
        "[Date_Updated]='" + DateU.Text + "',[Time_Updated]='" + TimeU.Text + "',[Updated_By]='" + UpdatedBy.Text + "'" + _
        "WHERE [Item]='" + com_ItemU.Text + "'"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()




    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error")
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

actually i still have no codes for it, i keep trying the codes i found in researching but nothing helps thats why i deleted it.

Comment: Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand 

If Not conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then 

conn.Open() End If 

Try cmd.Connection = conn 
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE BC_Inventory SET [Addition]='" + AddU.Text + "'," + _ "[Date_Updated]='" + DateU.Text + "',[Time_Updated]='" + TimeU.Text + "',[Updated_By]='" + UpdatedBy.Text + "'" + _ "WHERE [Item]='" + com_ItemU.Text + "'" cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error")
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try

Comment: Don't put code in a comment - you cannot format it.

Comment: What doesn't work here? Are you getting an exception, or incorrect behavior?

Comment: My codes works but it only adds a value to Addition field in my table, what i want is the codes for adding my value inputted in my AddU.text to the existing value in Quantity field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your quantity-field is a field in your table?
This is the changed SQL-Query.

```
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

If Not conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
    conn.Open()
End If

Try
    ' SQL-Query with Database Update on Field Quantity = Quantity + AddU.Text
    Dim strSQL As String = "" & _
        "UPDATE BC_Inventory " & _
        "SET [Addition]     = '" & AddU.Text & "', " & _
        "    [Quantity]     = CDbl([Quantity]) + CDbl(" & CDbl(AddU.Text.Replace(",", ".")) & "), " & _
        "    [Date_Updated] = '" & DateU.Text & "', " & _
        "    [Time_Updated] = '" & TimeU.Text & "', " & _
        "    [Updated_By]   = '" & UpdatedBy.Text & "' " & _
        "WHERE [Item] = '" & com_ItemU.Text & "' "

    ' For Debugging
    ' MsgBox(strSQL)

    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = strSQL
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error")
Finally
    conn.Close()
End Try
```

*Edit 1* :
A " sign was double in the line `"WHERE [Item] ..."`

*Edit 2* :
Changed `Convert(DOUBLE, Quantity)` to `Convert(DOUBLE, [Quantity])`

*Edit 3* : Remark for debugging.

```
' For Debugging
' MsgBox(strSQL)
```

*Edit 4* : Added the missing `)` to `Convert(DOUBLE, '" & CDbl(AddU.Text) & "', "` right at the end.

*Edit 5* : changed `)'` to `')`

*Edit 6* : Now with `CDec()` instead of `Convert(Double, )`

*Edit 7* : `CDbl(AddU.Text.Replace(",", "."))`

*Edit 8* : Removed the ' around the CDbl(AddU.Text)

*Edit 9* : replaced the `CDec` with `CDbl`

Comment: I ran your codes but it prompts an error. it says "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression".

Comment: Did you use the VB Code? I saw that there was i little syntax error in the the line with the WHERE-Clause. There was an doubled " at the end of this line. If fixed my sample above. Please try again.

Comment: Got it. There was a ) missing.

Comment: i think the error is in the operators because it says Syntax error (missing operator)

Comment: Then please check the MsgBox and show me the SQL-Query from the MsgBox.

Comment: Thank you sir but it now says "undefined function 'Convert' in expression".

Comment: I'm not out of ideas. Switchted from `Convert` to `CDec`

Comment: "Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression CDec([Quantity]) + CDec(AddU.Text)

Comment: Does the Value of AddU.Text contains a comma?

Comment: Please show me final SQL-Query (out of the MsgBox).

Comment: ahm, sir may i ask you one more, why did we use this .Replace(",", ".") and removed the ' after the " ?

Comment: Because your AddU.Text is a string, a text. Your number is like 123,45. The function Cdbl() expects only one expression. But the VB-Compiler reads Cdbl(123,45) like two expression (a comma is seperator for expressions). A a number in VB or SQL is always 123.45 (< a dot). So we replace the comma in the string AddU.Text with a dot from 123,45 to 123.45. And because of that we've got a real number so we don't need the ' für the string ( a ' is only needed for strings or dates). See here for CDbl() in SQL / MS-Access : http://goo.gl/omFRn2